# Input date format YYYYMMDD

Tags: sas

I need to input dates in YYYYMMDD format and create macro variables from these dates to use in a WHERE clause.  The FINAL dataset should select one record from Sales but 0 observations are returned.

```
data work.FiscalYear2019;
input @1 fiscalYear $4. @5 StartDate mmddyy8.;
retain diff;
if fiscalYear = '2019' then do;
    tday = today();
    diff = tday - StartDate;
    call symputx('FYTD_days',diff);
    call symputx('CY_StartDate', StartDate);
    call symputx('CY_EndDate', put(today(),mmddyy8.));
end;
else if fiscalYear = '2018' then do;
    PY_EndDate = StartDate + diff;
    call symput('PY_EndDate', put(PY_EndDate,mmddyy8.));
    call symput('PY_StartDate', put(StartDate,mmddyy8.));
end;

datalines;
201912312018
201801012018 
;
data work.Sales;
input @1 fiscalYear $4. @5 orderDate mmddyy8.;
format orderDate mmddyy6.;
datalines;
201902042019
201801012018
;
data final  (WHERE=(orderDate >= &PY_StartDate AND
                   orderDate <= &PY_EndDate));
set Sales;
run;
```

I expect the FINAL dataset to contain one record from the Sales dataset but FINAL has 0 observations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use your macro variables as date values you need to either generate the macro variables as the raw number of days values, like you did with CY_StartDate, or generate them using the DATE format and enclose them in quotes and append the letter D to make a date literal.

Like this:

```
call symputX('PY_StartDate', put(StartDate,date9.));
call symputX('PY_EndDate', PY_EndDate);
...
data final
  set Sales;
  WHERE orderDate >= "&PY_StartDate"d
   AND  orderDate <= &PY_EndDate
  ;
run;
```

Also your subject line mentions YYYYMMDD informat and it does not appear in your code.  Are you interpreting your source data properly?  Does `201801012018` represent an 8 digit date in YMD order plus a four digit year?  Or a four digit year plus an 8 digit date in MDY order?

Answer (score 0):

You are just not referring to your macro variables in the last data step with the proper syntax.  Those `&PY_StartDate` and `&PY_EndDate` variables are just strings after macro code is compiled, and you need to refer to them as date constants.  So this should fix the issue:

```
data final  (WHERE=(orderDate >= "&PY_StartDate"d AND
                   orderDate <= "&PY_EndDate"d));
set Sales;
run;
```

In the future, I recommend including `options mprint;` at the start of your code.  This option displays the text generated by macro execution in your log, which can help greatly with debugging macros.